App crashes silently after successfully creating link token with Plaid AndroidSDK
Here is the symptom
Here is the CreateLinkToken composable
@Composable
fun CreateLinkToken(
    onBackPressed: () -> Unit = {},
    onPaymentSuccess: () -> Unit = {},
    onPaymentFailure: () -> Unit = {},
    onPaymentCancelled: () -> Unit = {},
    viewModel: PlaidViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    val linkToken = viewModel.linkToken
    Timber.d("linkToken: $linkToken")

    BackHandler(
        enabled = true,
        onBack = {
            onBackPressed()
        },
    )

    val linkAccountToPlaid = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(FastOpenPlaidLink()) { result ->
        Timber.d("launchResult, plaid: $result")
        when (result) {
            is LinkSuccess -> {
                Timber.d("LinkSuccess, plaid: $result")

                onPaymentSuccess()
            }

            is LinkExit -> {
                Timber.d("LinkExit, plaid: $result")

                onPaymentCancelled()
            }

            else -> {
                Timber.d("launchResult, plaid: $result")
            }
        }
    }

    linkToken?.let {
        val linkTokenConfiguration = linkTokenConfiguration {
            token = it
            logLevel = LinkLogLevel.VERBOSE
        }
        val plaidHandler: PlaidHandler = Plaid.create(
            application = LocalContext.current.applicationContext as Application,
            linkTokenConfiguration,
        )

        SideEffect {
            linkAccountToPlaid.launch(plaidHandler)
        }
    }

    Plaid.setLinkEventListener { event ->
        Timber.d("event, plaid: $event")
    }
}

The linkToken here is guaranteed to be fresh and valid, with a request body
{
    "client_id": "{{PlaidSandboxClientId}}",
    "secret": "{{PlaidSandboxSecret}}",
    "client_name": "PlaidTestApp",
    "user": {
        "client_user_id": "{{ClientIdButNotPlaidClientId}}"
    },
    "products": [
        "auth",
        "transactions"
    ],
    "country_codes": [
        "US"
    ],
    "language": "en"
}

android_package_name and redirect_uri removed to simplify the problem.
Here are related logs during the whole process, of creating link token from Plaid:
2024-11-01 17:27:04.650  2093-2093  ScrollOpti...neManager] com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  updateCurrentActivity: mCurrentActivityName=com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity, isOptEnable=true, isAnimAheadEnable=true, isFrameInsertEnable=true, InsertNum=1, isEnabledForScrollChanged=false
2024-11-01 17:27:04.650  2093-2093  ActivityThread          com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  ComponentInfo{com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity} checkFinished=false 2
2024-11-01 17:27:04.678  2093-2093  ViewRootImplExtImpl     com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  wrapConfigInfoIntoFlags rotation=0, smallestScreenWidthDp=384, relayoutAsync=false, newFlags=25165824, title=com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity
2024-11-01 17:27:04.697  2093-2093  SurfaceControl          com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     I   setExtendedRangeBrightness sc=Surface(name=com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity)/@0x45374e7,currentBufferRatio=1.0,desiredRatio=1.0
2024-11-01 17:27:05.563  2093-2093  ViewRootImplExtImpl     com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  wrapConfigInfoIntoFlags rotation=0, smallestScreenWidthDp=384, relayoutAsync=true, newFlags=25165824, title=com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity
2024-11-01 17:27:05.568  2093-2093  SurfaceControl          com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     I   setExtendedRangeBrightness sc=Surface(name=com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity)/@0x45374e7,currentBufferRatio=1.0,desiredRatio=1.0
2024-11-01 17:27:05.749  2093-2308  OplusScrollToTopManager com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity,This DecorView@12845fc[LinkActivity] change focus to true
2024-11-01 17:27:07.419  2093-2093  CreateLinkTokenKt       com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  event, plaid: LinkEvent(eventName=TRANSITION_VIEW, metadata=LinkEventMetadata(brandName=null, errorCode=, errorMessage=, errorType=, exitStatus=, institutionId=, institutionName=, institutionSearchQuery=, linkSessionId=90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949, mfaType=, requestId=CajCcvidZuUcLRT, selection=null, timestamp=2024-11-02T00:27:07.131Z, viewName=com.plaid.link.event.LinkEventViewName$CONSENT@b94118b, metadataJson={"account_number_mask":"","error_code":"","error_message":"","error_type":"","exit_status":"","institution_id":"","institution_name":"","institution_search_query":"","is_update_mode":"","link_session_id":"90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949","match_reason":"","mfa_type":"","request_id":"CajCcvidZuUcLRT","routing_number":"","timestamp":"","view_name":"CONSENT"}, routingNumber=null, isUpdateMode=, matchReason=, accountNumberMask=))
2024-11-01 17:27:07.423  2093-2093  CreateLinkTokenKt       com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  event, plaid: LinkEvent(eventName=OPEN, metadata=LinkEventMetadata(brandName=null, errorCode=, errorMessage=, errorType=, exitStatus=, institutionId=, institutionName=, institutionSearchQuery=, linkSessionId=90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949, mfaType=, requestId=CajCcvidZuUcLRT, selection=null, timestamp=2024-11-02T00:27:07.382Z, viewName=com.plaid.link.event.LinkEventViewName$CONSENT@b94118b, metadataJson={"account_number_mask":"","error_code":"","error_message":"","error_type":"","exit_status":"","institution_id":"","institution_name":"","institution_search_query":"","is_update_mode":"false","link_session_id":"90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949","match_reason":"","mfa_type":"","request_id":"CajCcvidZuUcLRT","routing_number":"","timestamp":"","view_name":"CONSENT"}, routingNumber=null, isUpdateMode=false, matchReason=, accountNumberMask=))
2024-11-01 17:27:15.748  2093-2093  CreateLinkTokenKt       com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  event, plaid: LinkEvent(eventName=TRANSITION_VIEW, metadata=LinkEventMetadata(brandName=null, errorCode=, errorMessage=, errorType=, exitStatus=, institutionId=, institutionName=, institutionSearchQuery=, linkSessionId=90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949, mfaType=, requestId=jL0K63BkqrfVdoa, selection=null, timestamp=2024-11-02T00:27:11.058Z, viewName=com.plaid.link.event.LinkEventViewName$SELECT_INSTITUTION@61ae681, metadataJson={"account_number_mask":"","error_code":"","error_message":"","error_type":"","exit_status":"","institution_id":"","institution_name":"","institution_search_query":"","is_update_mode":"","link_session_id":"90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949","match_reason":"","mfa_type":"","request_id":"jL0K63BkqrfVdoa","routing_number":"","timestamp":"","view_name":"SELECT_INSTITUTION"}, routingNumber=null, isUpdateMode=, matchReason=, accountNumberMask=))
2024-11-01 17:27:15.794  2093-2093  CreateLinkTokenKt       com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  event, plaid: LinkEvent(eventName=TRANSITION_VIEW, metadata=LinkEventMetadata(brandName=null, errorCode=, errorMessage=, errorType=, exitStatus=, institutionId=ins_56, institutionName=Chase, institutionSearchQuery=, linkSessionId=90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949, mfaType=, requestId=w6I9DLeUJyMYonb, selection=null, timestamp=2024-11-02T00:27:13.875Z, viewName=com.plaid.link.event.LinkEventViewName$OAUTH@64cdd14, metadataJson={"account_number_mask":"","error_code":"","error_message":"","error_type":"","exit_status":"","institution_id":"ins_56","institution_name":"Chase","institution_search_query":"","is_update_mode":"","link_session_id":"90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949","match_reason":"","mfa_type":"","request_id":"w6I9DLeUJyMYonb","routing_number":"","timestamp":"","view_name":"OAUTH"}, routingNumber=null, isUpdateMode=, matchReason=, accountNumberMask=))
2024-11-01 17:27:15.815  2093-2093  CreateLinkTokenKt       com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  event, plaid: LinkEvent(eventName=OPEN_OAUTH, metadata=LinkEventMetadata(brandName=null, errorCode=, errorMessage=, errorType=, exitStatus=, institutionId=ins_56, institutionName=Chase, institutionSearchQuery=, linkSessionId=90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949, mfaType=, requestId=w6I9DLeUJyMYonb, selection=null, timestamp=2024-11-02T00:27:15.703Z, viewName=null, metadataJson={"account_number_mask":"","error_code":"","error_message":"","error_type":"","exit_status":"","institution_id":"ins_56","institution_name":"Chase","institution_search_query":"","is_update_mode":"","link_session_id":"90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949","match_reason":"","mfa_type":"","request_id":"w6I9DLeUJyMYonb","routing_number":"","timestamp":"","view_name":""}, routingNumber=null, isUpdateMode=, matchReason=, accountNumberMask=))
2024-11-01 17:27:15.822  2093-2093  CreateLinkTokenKt       com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  event, plaid: LinkEvent(eventName=SELECT_INSTITUTION, metadata=LinkEventMetadata(brandName=null, errorCode=, errorMessage=, errorType=, exitStatus=, institutionId=ins_56, institutionName=Chase, institutionSearchQuery=null, linkSessionId=90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949, mfaType=, requestId=jL0K63BkqrfVdoa, selection=null, timestamp=2024-11-02T00:27:12.541Z, viewName=null, metadataJson={"account_number_mask":"","error_code":"","error_message":"","error_type":"","exit_status":"","institution_id":"","institution_name":"","institution_search_query":"","is_update_mode":"","link_session_id":"90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949","match_reason":"","mfa_type":"","request_id":"jL0K63BkqrfVdoa","routing_number":"","timestamp":"","view_name":""}, routingNumber=null, isUpdateMode=, matchReason=, accountNumberMask=))
2024-11-01 17:27:16.862  2093-2308  OplusScrollToTopManager com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity,This DecorView@12845fc[LinkActivity] change focus to false
2024-11-01 17:27:16.907  2093-2093  ViewRootImplExtImpl     com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  wrapConfigInfoIntoFlags rotation=0, smallestScreenWidthDp=384, relayoutAsync=false, newFlags=25165824, title=com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity
2024-11-01 17:27:30.627  2093-2093  ScrollOpti...neManager] com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  updateCurrentActivity: mCurrentActivityName=com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity, isOptEnable=true, isAnimAheadEnable=true, isFrameInsertEnable=true, InsertNum=1, isEnabledForScrollChanged=false
2024-11-01 17:27:30.627  2093-2093  ActivityThread          com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  ComponentInfo{com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity} checkFinished=false 2
2024-11-01 17:27:30.638  2093-2093  ViewRootImplExtImpl     com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  wrapConfigInfoIntoFlags rotation=0, smallestScreenWidthDp=384, relayoutAsync=false, newFlags=25165824, title=com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity
2024-11-01 17:27:30.676  2093-2093  SurfaceControl          com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     I   setExtendedRangeBrightness sc=Surface(name=com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity)/@0x45374e7,currentBufferRatio=1.0,desiredRatio=1.0
2024-11-01 17:27:31.742  2093-2308  OplusScrollToTopManager com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity,This DecorView@12845fc[LinkActivity] change focus to true

Here are the related logs after I pressed "Continue" on the Success screen
2024-11-01 17:28:17.933  2093-2093  CreateLinkTokenKt       com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  event, plaid: LinkEvent(eventName=HANDOFF, metadata=LinkEventMetadata(brandName=null, errorCode=, errorMessage=, errorType=, exitStatus=, institutionId=ins_56, institutionName=Chase, institutionSearchQuery=, linkSessionId=90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949, mfaType=, requestId=NVOBiQ8ySOSGtmz, selection=null, timestamp=2024-11-02T00:28:17.868Z, viewName=null, metadataJson={"account_number_mask":"","error_code":"","error_message":"","error_type":"","exit_status":"","institution_id":"ins_56","institution_name":"Chase","institution_search_query":"","is_update_mode":"","link_session_id":"90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949","match_reason":"","mfa_type":"","request_id":"NVOBiQ8ySOSGtmz","routing_number":"","timestamp":"","view_name":""}, routingNumber=null, isUpdateMode=, matchReason=, accountNumberMask=))
2024-11-01 17:28:17.946  2093-2093  CreateLinkTokenKt       com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  event, plaid: LinkEvent(eventName=TRANSITION_VIEW, metadata=LinkEventMetadata(brandName=null, errorCode=, errorMessage=, errorType=, exitStatus=, institutionId=ins_56, institutionName=Chase, institutionSearchQuery=, linkSessionId=90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949, mfaType=, requestId=ru1qoE2DLJIriKw, selection=null, timestamp=2024-11-02T00:27:35.079Z, viewName=com.plaid.link.event.LinkEventViewName$CONNECTED@eebd35, metadataJson={"account_number_mask":"","error_code":"","error_message":"","error_type":"","exit_status":"","institution_id":"ins_56","institution_name":"Chase","institution_search_query":"","is_update_mode":"","link_session_id":"90fba403-bdb2-40c5-b29a-722a249fd949","match_reason":"","mfa_type":"","request_id":"ru1qoE2DLJIriKw","routing_number":"","timestamp":"","view_name":"CONNECTED"}, routingNumber=null, isUpdateMode=, matchReason=, accountNumberMask=))
2024-11-01 17:28:18.203  2093-2093  OplusScrollToTopManager com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity,window dying
2024-11-01 17:28:18.203  2093-2093  OplusScrollToTopManager com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity,unregisterSystemUIBroadcastReceiver 
2024-11-01 17:28:18.203  2093-2093  OplusScrollToTopManager com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug     D  com.idiotleon.gameday.demo.debug/com.plaid.internal.link.LinkActivity, unregisterSystemUIBroadcastReceiver failed java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.view.OplusScrollToTopManager$2@562011e


Where is the crash log?

I cannot find any more. The last segment of this paragaph contains all the crash logs I can find.
